# how do you apply some script to every css element with the same id?

Tags: jquery

**HTML :**

```
<div id="tab">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="tab">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="tab">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="tab">This is a paragraph.</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#tab{
  height:30px;
  width:130px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function randomNumber() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
    }
    $('#tab').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ')');
    });
    $('#tab').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab').css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

I have this fiddle and I want the color change to affect ALL the #tabs, not just the first one, how do i do it?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhirkovski/nHCXV/) example can be found here.

Comment: the id are unique, change to class

Comment: you need to set same class for this..ids must be unique in a page

Comment: Can't, because #tabs equals an id (#). and an ID can only be assigned to 1 element, one time. you need to use an class (.), that will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only assign an ID once! Change it to classes like this http://jsfiddle.net/nHCXV/3/

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was after :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead. then you can access them all using

```
 $('.classname')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the id attribute as class because the id is unique. Let try this is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/nHCXV/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an fiddle witch the right way:

[http://jsfiddle.net/ToBadForU/9p7ud/](http://jsfiddle.net/ToBadForU/9p7ud/1/)

This is what you want, right?

Comment: I think he wants on every elements

Comment: @CharlesJourdan, you're right, but i didn't save it right... I've updated the link

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving same `id`'s you can declare the `div`'s without any `id`'s or `class` and give the code below. To know more about selectors go to this [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
}
$('div').mouseover(function() {
    $('div').css('background-color', 'rgb(' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ')');
});
$('div').mouseout(function() {
    $('div').css('background-color', 'white');
  });
});​
```

or else simply use `class` instead of `id`'s. 
[Because id's are unique but not classes](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

Comment: This would affect all other div's too so assigning classes would be the best choice.

Comment: It can be achieved by using jquery selectors. I updated my answer :)